# The differential equation $y'=y+1$ has no singular solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

$\frac{dy}{dx}=y+1$

Solving the above given differential equation, yields the following general solution.
$y+1=e^{x+C}$

$y=Ce^{x}-1$

$\implies$ Solution $y=-1$ at $C=0$

Can I say that $y= -1$ is a singular solution?

Comment: That's an ordinary solution. You may call it *trivial* if you want.

Comment: You shouldn’t change the meaning of $C$ there. Use an index or something. $y=C_1e^x-1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Why?  $C$ isn't a constant, a value, a parameter, or a variable.  I agree that the set of functions $\mathrm{e}^{x+C}$ is **not** the set of functions $C \mathrm{e}^x$, but not for the reason you mention (which is that somehow "the set of all constants" is different from "the set of all constants") but because negative constants must be excluded from the second usage.  That is $\mathrm{e}^{x+C} > 0$ for all choices of $x$ and choices of constant to replace $C$, but $C \mathrm{e}^x$ is negative if the choice of constant to replace $C$ is negative.

Comment: The formula $y+1=e^{x+C}$ is *not* the correct general solution (assuming that all quantites are real rather than complex), since it only accounts for solutions $y > -1$. Did you get it using separation of variables? Then you need to be more careful with the cases $y=-1$ and $y<-1$. (If you use an integrating factor instead, this problem never arises.)

Answer (score 2):

$y=-1$ is not a singular solution because it is included in the general solution $y=Ce^x-1$ when $C=0$. Solutions are only called singular when they are not attainable from the general solution form. In fact, I believe all linear first order homogenous equations have no singular solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$y=-1$ is not a singular solution, because it does not pass by any point $(x_0,y_0)$ such that the initial value problem $\begin{cases} y'=y+1\\ y(x_0)=y_0\end{cases}$ has more than one solution: in point of fact, the Cauchy problem $$\begin{cases}y'=y+1\\ y(x_0)=-1\end{cases}$$ has only the one maximal solution $y=-1$, whatever $x_0$ is.